# WP_Query - Load delay with multiple meta_query

Tags: wordpress, args

I have a Wordpress site that uses quite a few filters to display jobs.

The query will filter jobs by:-

- The Job Type
- The Location
- Job Sector
- If it is an International Job
- Will check the salary between two values

The current query I am running is:-

```
    <?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
        'post_type'     => 'jobs',
        'order'             => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'paged' => $paged,
        's' => $search_field,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'job_type',
                'value'     => $job_type,
                'compare'   => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'job_location',
                'value'     => $job_location,
                'compare'   => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'job_sector',
                'value'     => $job_sector,
                'compare'   => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'international_job',
                'value'     => $international_job,
                'type'    => 'numeric',
                'compare'   => 'IN',
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'job_location',
                'value'     => $location_array,
                'compare'   => 'NOT IN',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'       => 'anual_to_salary',
                    'value'     => array($job_salary_from,$job_salary_to),
                    'type'    => 'numeric',
                    'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'       => 'anual_from_salary',
                    'value'     => array($job_salary_from,$job_salary_to),
                    'type'    => 'numeric',
                    'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'       => 'job_negotiable',
                    'value'     => 'yes',
                    'compare'   => '=',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        )
    );

    $fetch_jobs = new WP_Query( $args );?>
```

I'm assuming this is a bad way to do this kind of query as it's taking around 5 - 10 seconds to display any results.

Can anyone recommend a better way to do this type of query with multiple filters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all Your code is like a charm, there is no better way to execute wp_query();. it is taking 5 to 10 second because there is lot of conditions to check and it totally depends on the data on which it have to perform filtration.

I saw whole code and just need a little change that you pass same argument twice i.e. posts_per_page please correct it. else it is the best to perform wp_query.